# MongoDB Atlas failing, could not find user

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy, mongodb-authentication

I’m trying to connect to the atlas cluster from mongoDb compose I keep getting the following error. What might be the reason for this? and what will help to resolve this problem?

Error:

```
Could not find user "arn:aws:iam::123545332123:user/iam_user" for db "$external"
```

Steps i followed:

1). From compose>Advance connection options>Authentication>AWS IAM
[image]

2). Click connect.
3). this error i am getting

```
Could not find user "arn:aws:iam::123545332123:user/iam_user" for db "$external"
```

**Note: I copied aws IAM Access Key ID, Secret access Key, and session token from single sign-on (SSO)**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Is the URI you've posted including "localhost:27017" for demonstration purposes? If not, have you tried using the [connection string gathered from the Atlas UI](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/guides/atlas/connection-string/#get-connection-string)?

Comment: i dont want to disclose details so i just take screenshot with localhost:27017. I will check the link provided. Do you know why i keep receiving that error message?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Not too sure regarding the error. You can perhaps try setting the database user up to have the [atlasAdmin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-add-mongodb-users/#mongodb-atlasrole-Atlas-admin) role for troubleshooting purposes to confirm it's not any issues with what the user is able to access. You can also check you [haven't restricted it to any particular resource](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-add-mongodb-users/#optional-specify-the-resources-in-the-project-that-the-user-can-access-2) too.